# Count number of specific rows with respect to the id from a table and update the other table row's data with respect to the same id as in first table

Tags: mysql

if i want to count the number of rows(column: status) from a table on behalf of a specific product id then use these counts on each row of the other table having the same product to update 2nd table rows(column: status) what will be the exact query.table 2 has a foreign key of table 1. i tried alot and this is what i have done so far but still failed:

```
IF (SELECT count(*) from car_reservation_detail WHERE car_reservation_detail.status='deactive')<1 THEN UPDATE car_detail SET car_detail.`status`='active' WHERE car_detail.status='reserved'
END IF
```

EDITED:

there are two tables table1 and table 2

For e.g

```
table :1

car_id(P.K)     status    
1               reserved
2               reserved

table :2

res_id     car_ID(F.K)   status    
1          1             deactive
2          1             deactive
3          1             deactive
4          2             deactive
5          2             active
```

what i want to perform is count the status of all cars in table 2 on behalf of car_id and if it has status=active less than 1 than i want to change the status of table 1 to active. if you see the data car id=1 has status=active less than 1 in table 2, the status of car_id in table 1 should be now changed to active from reserved. i hope this might give you a hint what i am trying to acheive.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: can u relate or answer the question cuz i tried to check it but didn't found any @Strawberry

Comment: you really need to provide more information is what @Strawberry is saying.

right now all we have is a query, no data, no table schemas. give us something that we can actually look at as we have may have some insight into what you are trying to do, but have gaps in what we can provide as we don't have all the information.

Comment: @ttallierchio i have added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it work for you. Please refer the below query.

```
UPDATE car_detail SET car_detail.`status`='active' 
WHERE car_detail.car_id=(
    SELECT car_reservation_detail.car_ID FROM car_reservation_detail 
    WHERE car_reservation_detail.status='deactive' 
    GROUP BY car_reservation_detail.car_ID
    HAVING COUNT(car_reservation_detail.car_ID)<1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a query that essentially is checking to see if you have any rows that are "active" so you can use a left join on your update statement to make sure none have a status of "active".

this below query works on the sample data set you provided.

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN table_2 t2  on t1.car_id = t2.car_id 
                 AND t2.status = 'active' 
                 SET t1.status = 'active'
       WHERE t2.res_id is null and t1.status != 'active';
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i think i am not able to clear my question sorry about that. ok for one more time i just want to change the status of table 1 from reserved to active if the table 2 car_ids all rows has there status=deactive.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for helping @Amardeep Verma your answer gave me a hint to manage the query and this is how it is working

```
UPDATE car_detail c SET c.`status`='active'
WHERE c.status='reserved' AND c.car_detail_id IN(SELECT cr.car_detail_id FROM car_reservation_detail cr
    WHERE cr.status='deactive'AND cr.car_detail_id NOT IN (SELECT cr.car_detail_id from car_reservation_detail cr
    WHERE cr.status='active')
    GROUP BY cr.car_detail_id)
```